# Extract multiple strings between hot characters from a paragraph

Tags: python, python-3.x

Now I cant really find a way to title this but I can explain what I am going for in code.

So I am able to take a users comment and check to see if it has these "[[Keyword]]" modifiers. Now I want to expand it further to allow more than one.

This is what happens if a user inputs more than one modifier in a row current code.

```
#comment in this case is "I want to [[find]] [[this]] [[Special]] word."
# c is the comment.
body = c.body
# Finds the hot word
result = re.search("\[\[(.*)\]\]", body, re.IGNORECASE)
print(result)
```

Expected result:

```
>>>find this Special
```

Returned result:

```
>>>find]] [[this]] [[Special
```

Is there any way I can take every result and put it into some sort of array, so I can measure how long the array is and each result will correspond to a number

How I want it to work.

```
print(result[0] +'\n')
print(result[1] +'\n')
print(result[2] +'\n')
>>>find
>>>this
>>>Special
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.*` is *greedy* by default.  You want it to match in *non-greedy* mode so it matches as little as possible. You can do that by using `.*?` instead of `.*`.  You should also use `re.findall` to get all the matches instead of `re.search`, which will only return the first match.

```
>>> re.findall(r"\[\[(.*?)\]\]", body, re.IGNORECASE)
['find', 'this', 'special']
```

Comment: Thank you :) exactly what I wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

text = 'comment in this case is "I want to [[find]] [[this]] [[Special]] word.'

result = re.findall("(?:\[\[(.*?)\]\])", text)

for term in result:
    print(term + "\n")
```